# Why does Linux kernel lock-less list have head and node structs?

Tags: c, linux, linked-list, linux-kernel, lockless

I'm trying to understand the lock-less list in the Linux kernel.  This is defined in llist.h.  Why do they have two structs, to define a list:

```
struct llist_head {
    struct llist_node *first;
};

struct llist_node {
    struct llist_node *next;
};
```

Why not have just one struct that has a pointer to the next node?  It would similar to the doubly linked list implementation in the kernel.

Comment: Imagine, the list is empty, e.g. there is no single `node` in it...

Comment: The kernel's doubly linked list implementation (non lock-less) handles empty lists without having two structs.

Comment: Look that field names are named differently.  Think that you want to call the first element `first`, and not `next`.  This prevents some errors sourced from **copy&paste** programming, as the identifiers are not valid in the _other_ context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why do they have two structs, to define a list?

Because it is **possible** to use *different* struct (types) for *different* things (head and node correspondingly). Linux kernel tends to follow same convensions as for usual programming.

In case of double linked lists, both head and node are **forced to have the same type**: by design, both `next` and `prev` fields of `struct list_head` may point either to node or to the head. Single type for them is not an advantage, but *necessity*.

Comment: You can use `union {struct head a; struct node b;}` and make your pointer a pointer to the `union` instead.... _necessity_ can be ok for a first prototype, but in quality code you **must type differently things that are different**.

Comment: @LuisColorado, but you have to take care about union aliasing (should not to happen in your code).